# how to use HttpSendRequest with tor hidden web server

Tags: http, file-upload, tor

I am trying to send data from an application to a php script running on a web server using the following code:

```
#define server_add "mywebsite.com"
HINTERNET h = InternetOpen(USER_AGENT,INTERNET_OPEN_TYPE_PRECONFIG,NULL,NULL,0);
h = InternetConnect(h,CNC,INTERNET_DEFAULT_HTTP_PORT,"","",INTERNET_SERVICE_HTTP,0,0);
h = HttpOpenRequest(h,"POST",server_add,NULL,NULL,NULL,0,0);
HttpSendRequest(h,"Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\r\n",47,buffer,strlen(buffer)) //buffer is holding data that I want to send
InternetCloseHandle(h);
```

The code works when server_add is set to a clearnet address such as mywebsite.com, fails at HttpSendRequest when server_add is set to a tor hidden server address such as http://mywebsite.onion, or http://mywebsite.tor2web.org.

Can someone point out the error in my approach to sending data to a hidden server?

Answer (score 0):

Tor's hidden service ".onion" names aren't actual internet host names, and can't be translated to an IP address through the normal DNS name resolution system, because Tor hidden servers don't have (known) normal IP addresses at all; they can only be reached securely by using the Tor software to go through the whole Tor multi-hop anonymization network process. When you try to connect to "mysite.onion" with the above code, it goes to your system's configured DNS service and asks it for the IP address that corresponds to "mysite.onion" and is rightly told there's no such address on the internet. You'd have the same problem if you tried to access mysite.onion with a normal non-Tor web browser with no Tor software installed.

If you install the standard Tor browser bundle, one of the things it takes care of for you is configuring its embedded copy of Firefox to intercept your typed in URL and look for the .onion suffix, and route those connection attempts through the Tor network instead of using the normal direct internet for them. But that obviously won't do any good if you want to code your own app, whose connections won't be going through the preconfigured browser. To use .onion addresses from within your own app, instead of trying to directly connect to mysite.onion, you need to connect to the Tor software's built-in SOCKS proxy server feature, which acts as an intermediary to take messages targeted for Tor .onion URLs and pass them through the Tor network to the hidden server, and then pass the responses back to your app.

Added: WinINet (the library which provides those calls above) can be told to use a SOCKS proxy connection, assuming you have Internet Explorer installed on your computer. Note you don't have to actually run Internet Explorer at all, but installing it upgrades the default Windows WinINet library with an improved version that includes SOCKS capability. Of course, IE comes preinstalled on almost all versions of Windows now anyway, so it's probably not an issue.

To tell WinINet to use SOCKS, change your InternetOpen call to something like (assuming the default Tor SOCKS port number):

```
h = InternetOpen(USER_AGENT, INTERNET_OPEN_TYPE_PROXY, "SOCKS=localhost:9050", NULL, 0);
```

However, there are possible complications (of course!), and I haven't actually used this myself. There are multiple versions of the SOCKS protocol in use (generally 4, 4a, and 5) and I'm not sure exactly which version(s) Tor and IE actually support, or how well WinINet does at negotiating to find one in common.

If SOCKS doesn't work, WinINet also includes the ability to use an HTTP proxy instead (same purpose as SOCKS, just a different protocol for telling it who to connect to). However, since Tor doesn't understand HTTP proxy connections itself, you'd have to add another intermediate software layer to handle translating between HTTP proxy requests and Tor's SOCKS support. Luckily there are excellent free HTTP proxy handlers available for Windows, the best probably being [Privoxy](http://www.privoxy.org/), which is [often used with Tor](http://www.privoxy.org/faq/misc.html#TOR) since it also adds some key security features like carefully sanitizing your HTTP request headers to make sure they don't leak any identifying info to the Tor hidden server, if that's an issue (even if you trust the Tor server's admins, their server could conceivably be found and seized some day and all their traffic get logged).

To tell WinINet to use an HTTP proxy, use something like (with the default Privoxy port number):

```
h = InternetOpen(USER_AGENT, INTERNET_OPEN_TYPE_PROXY, "http=http://localhost:8118", NULL, 0);
```

and you should be up and running.

Comment: Is socket programming required even if my application tries to transfer its data via www-to-onion proxies such as tor2web.org or onion.to which will be communicating with the application over the regular http port 80?

Comment: Theoretically your original code should have worked with those, but I've found them to be very unreliable, maybe due to heavy traffic. I wouldn't use them anyway since they can't protect the user's id or info between the user's computer and their site, and may in fact have all their traffic on the clearnet side monitored and logged (seems an easy and obvious way to catch those trying to use Silk Road, etc).